# Sync-Settings restore failure: "no such file or directory, open..."

Tags: atom-editor

After installing atom on a certain station I have equipped it with all the required packages. Then I have installed "sync-settings", for the purpose of cloning the atom setup for all the other stations in my LAB. Till this point everything looks OK. All the contents was uploaded as it was supposed to, and I find it in the gist that I have created.

Now I have tried to install atom on several more stations and after installing the "sync-settings" package (along with setting up all the gist and github details) I have tried to perform a sync-settings:restore action.

It looks like sync-settings is looking for the same path (as the one that was synchronized in the beginning) and therefore when I try to perform the restore it fails due to "no such file or directory, open...".

What should I do in order to be able to restore the packages when I actually do it with different users (and stations) which causes the path to sync to be different. Is it possible to do that ?

Note: the full message looks like "Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\newprivate.atom\C:\Users\originalprivate.atom\config.cson'" (new private and originalprivate are replacing the user and domain names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply editing the **config.cson** file path. All I needed to do in order to be able to Restore the settings into other stations with Atom, was to remove the part of the path which was unique to the station that I fully set with Atom (the one that I backed up its settings)